# Не работает box-sizing

Tags: css3, html, frontend, вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте. Есть след. разметка:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Магазин</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="cols col-4">Один</div>
        <div class="cols col-4">Два</div>
        <div class="cols col-4">Три</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Есть след. css:

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
    font:100%/1.5em Arial,Helvetica sans-serif;
    color:#000;
}
#container{
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#d2d2d2;
}
#container .cols{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 0 1em;
    padding:0 1em;
    background:#fd4;
}
.col-1{width:8.333333333333333%;}
.col-2{width:16.66666666666667%;}
.col-3{width:25%;}
.col-4{width:33.33333333333333%;}
.col-5{width:41.66666666666667%;}
.col-6{width:50%;}
.col-7{width:58.33333333333333%;}
.col-8{width:66.66666666666666%;}
.col-9{width:75%;}
.col-10{width:83.33333333333333%;}
.col-11{width:91.66666666666666%;}
.col-12{width:100%;}
```

Проблема в этом коде в том, что почему-то не срабатывает box-sizing и третья колонка не помещается. Как только ставлю в #container .cols вместj display:inline-block правило float:left все срабатывает как надо.

[Код на jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nahuhawi/3/edit).

Почему не работает box-sizing в данном случае?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому-что между div-ами есть переводы строк, они воспринимаются как пробелы, пробелы имеют ширину, три блока шириной (100/3)% плюс ширины пробелов это больше 100% и потому в одну строку не влезает.

Такая вот мелкая пакость с инлайновыми блоками. Можно обойти убрав переводы строк и пробелы между блоками, или задав родительскому элементу ширину пробела равную 0 (в дочерних элементах её придётся восстанавливать).

Answer (score 3):

У тебя пробелы между блоками, попробуй вот так:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="cols col-4">Один</div><div class="cols col-4">Два</div><div class="cols col-4">Три</div>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/nahuhawi/9/edit

т.е. чтобы между объявлением нового и закрытием старого не было пробелов. Вроде есть ещё решение на чистом css, можешь погуглить в эту сторону.

update: да, float: left - это другое решение

ну да, по теме хорошая [статья](http://css-live.ru/articles/zagadochnye-otstupy-mezhdu-inlajn-blokami.html)

Comment: Долго-же я писал (: